# Firebase Facebook login popup does not let you pick different account

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm working on adding Facebook and Google login to an app. So far so good with the Google side of things, ot works but not the Facebook. I found out that having two emails linked to different accounts causes a problem so I handled it in the `catch()` of `loginWithProvider()`.

The problem I have is that I cannot get the user to pick another account. The Facebook login popup opens, detects that there is another account with that email and opens the Google popup. I want to let the user choose the Facebook account to log in with. I thought the `prompt: "select_account"` would fix it but it does not.

Here is my code:

```js
const loginWithProvider = (provider, onSuccess) => async dispatch => {
  Firebase.auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(result => {
      // register the user in my backend here
    })
    .catch(({ code, email }) => {
      if (code === "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential") {
        Firebase.auth()
          .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
          .then(providers => {
            if (providers.includes("google.com")) {
              dispatch(
                loginWithGoogle(onSuccess, {
                  login_hint: email
                })
              );
            }
          });
      }
    })
    .then(() => isFunction(onSuccess) && onSuccess());
};

export const loginWithFacebook = (onSuccess, parameters) => async dispatch => {
  const provider = new Firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  provider.setCustomParameters({ ...parameters, prompt: "select_account" });
  dispatch(loginWithProvider(provider, onSuccess));
};

export const loginWithGoogle = (onSuccess, parameters) => async dispatch => {
  const provider = new Firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  provider.setCustomParameters({ ...parameters, prompt: "select_account" });
  dispatch(loginWithProvider(provider, onSuccess));
};
```

Any ideas?

Edit: After some research it turns out that `prompt: "select_account"` is valid for the Google popup but not for the Facebook one. I'm struggling to find what do I need to use for Facebook's.

Comment: Hello, Any update on this issue?

Comment: None, unfortunately :(

Comment: Does anyone have any update now?